# Why is the path to an image changing in my shared nav bar?

Tags: jekyll

I am building a static site in jekyll with a shared navigation bare in the `_includes` folder (`_nav.html`)

It includes an svg of a logo. Whenever I navigate to the documentation page, the site cannot find the logo.

On all other pages the navigation to the logo is

```
assets/img/logo.svg
```

But when I inspect the missing element on the docs page the path has changed to

```
docs/assets/img/logo.svg
```

I noticed that the url for the docs page is `localhost:4000/docs/` but all the others do not end in with the `/`.

I have set up the links in my `config.yml` file:

```
global_nav:
  - title: Home
    id: home
  - title: Documentation
    id: docs
  - title: Support
    id: support
```

I have run `jekyll clean` to clear caches but nothing has worked.

Comment: By adding `assets/img/logo.svg` (without a full URL or a beginning `/`) you are getting a relative URL. If you're in the docs directory you'll get that appended to the URL. I'd need to see the repo to give more tailored advice, but try one of these: `<img src="{{ '/assets/img/logo.svg' | absolute_url }}">` or `<img src="{{ '/assets/img/logo.svg' | relative_url }}">`.

Comment: Hi! That worked, thank you!